# Constructors overloading in Java

Tags: java

```
class parent {
    String s;

    parent() {
         this(10);
         this.s = "First";
    }
    parent(int a){
         this(10.00f);
         this.s += "Second";
    }
    parent(float b){
         this("sss");
         this.s += "Third";
    }
    parent(String c){
         this('a');
         this.s += "Fourth";
    }
    parent(char d){
         this.s = "Fifth"; 
         System.out.println(this.s);
    }
}

class chain {
    static public void main(String[] string) {
        parent p = new parent();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Fifth
```

I expected the following would be the flow

```
parent()->parent(int a)->parent(float b)->parent(String c)->parent(char d).
```

This happens but once the last constructor is executed I thought the remaining String, float, int and no-arg constructor variants would be executed because they do have code to process and is it not how they work.

I assume that constructors' execution is stack based (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: It **is** stack based. Add `System.out.println(this.s);` to each constructor and see the result.

Comment: System.out.println missing and this.s += are the culprits..Tx Eric/lulyon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right and wrong.

The remaining code in the other constructors *does* execute, but you print out the value of `this.s` before they do.

Here is the flow of your code, in vertical chronological order:

```
parent()
  this(10)
    this(10.00f)
      this("sss")
        this('a')
          this.s = "Fifth"
          System.out.println(this.s)
        this.s += "Fourth"
      this.s += "Third"
    this.s += "Second"
  this.s = "First"
```

You'll either need to print out `p.s` after `new parent()`, or move your print statement to the end of `parent()` (and change `= "First"` to `+= "First"`).

Comment: Thanks Eric..i got it now

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Eric pointed out the actual issue, which is that you are printing out `this.s` after it has only been modified once. Also as he says, if you had `+=` in all the right places, they would be concatenated in the opposite order of what you are expecting.

Note that there is a major problem with these constructors in that if you use any one other than the first, it will error out due to a null reference. You should have:

```
if(this.s == null){
   this.s = "";
}
```

at the beginning of all the constructors except the first.

Comment: `this.s = "Fifth"` is executed before any of the `+=` statements are, so I doubt this is the issue.

Comment: I agree with Eric. Because when I keep this.s += "Fifth"..I get nullFifth as the output.

Answer (score 0):

You're only seeing `Fifth` because your System.out.println() call is right after `this.s = "Fifth";`

If you add a System.out.println after every addition to s, you get:

```
Fifth
FifthFourth
FifthFourthThird
FifthFourthThirdSecond
First
```

First resets it because you used `=` there instead of `+=`. Fix that, and you get:

```
Fifth
FifthFourth
FifthFourthThird
FifthFourthThirdSecond
FifthFourthThirdSecondFirst
```